# Blazor Server app not working with Edge but working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, server, blazor

We have an existing Blazor server application that we've developed that has some pages suddenly become unresponsive when using Edge, however the same application works as expected when using Chrome.

When inspecting the console output in Edge there is no indication of any error.  When debugging in VS 2022, no breakpoints are hit in the unresponsive pages so we've got little information about the what/why of the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Details:

> VS 2022 Enterprise v17.3.6
>
> Edge v107.0.1418.26 (Official build) (64-bit)
>
> Chrome v106.0.6249.121 (Official build) (32-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug the application using Edge or Chrome in **incognito** mode.
Use a new configuration like this one:
[image: Edge in Incognito]

then select the new configuration in debug mode:
[image: Debug with Edge Incognito]

the problem should be an extension.

Answer (score 0):

After chasing down multiple possible causes to this behavior we finally solved the issue by creating a new VS project and then migrated the source files from the original project into the new project.  This solved the issue.